# How to set the color of highlighted section in beamer sidebar to frametitle color

Tags: beamer

I am simply trying to do this in the preamble:

```
\setbeamercolor{palette sidebar secondary}{fg=\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}}
```

But it does not work (the file does not compile, and I get the `rerunfilecheck` warning). I am using the Hannover theme, with a left sidebar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Hannover}

  % to change the frame title color
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=purple}

 % to set the section color the same as the frame title color   
\setbeamercolor{section in sidebar}{use=frametitle,fg=frametitle.fg} 

\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\begin{frame}{Frame within the first section}

\end{frame}
\section{Second section}
\begin{frame}{Frame within the second section}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]